# Systemd cannot find bluetooth service

Tags: systemd, bluetooth, bluez

I am on Manjaro with kernel 5.15.28-1

My problem relates to bluetooth. I have bluez 5.61-1 (which I downgraded from 5.63-2).

I can activate bluetooth with systemctl but not from a systemd service that I wrote:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/bt-restart.service

 [Unit]
 Description=restart bt and connect keypad

 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 User=root

 RemainAfterExit=yes

 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 1
 ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 3
 ExecStart=/home/jcw/bin/enable-bt.sh

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Output from

> sudo systemctl status bt-restart

```
● bt-restart.service - restart bt and connect keypad
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bt-restart.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2022-03-19 09:00:35 CET; 1h 27min ago
    Process: 2762 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2763 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2764 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2766 ExecStart=/home/jcw/bin/enable-bt.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2766 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 41ms

mars 19 08:59:50 jcw-k30amjafk31amj systemd[1]: Starting restart bt and connect keypad...
mars 19 08:59:51 jcw-k30amjafk31amj systemd[2763]: bt-restart.service: Executable /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth missing,>
mars 19 09:00:35 jcw-k30amjafk31amj enable-bt.sh[2767]: Attempting to connect to 2B:24:13:DB:7C:99
mars 19 09:00:35 jcw-k30amjafk31amj enable-bt.sh[2767]: Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
mars 19 09:00:35 jcw-k30amjafk31amj systemd[1]: Finished restart bt and connect keypad.
```

As you can see from **Executable /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth missing**, systemd did not find bluetooth.service.

But the file exists. It can be reached by systemctl. So what?

EDIT: End of the second line is "Executable /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth missing, skipping: No such file or directory"

Comment: The `>` at the end of the message `Executable /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth missing,>` indicates there is more text that was cut off. It's probably `Executable ... missing, or <some other error condition that might be applicable in this case>`. Use `systemctl status -l bt-restart`: you won't need `sudo` when you're just querying a service status.

Comment: You're right. The line is ending with "Executable /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth missing, skipping: No such file or directory"

Comment: `As you can see from Executable /usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth missing, systemd did not find bluetooth.service.` How did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no executable files in directory `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`.

There might be a `/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`, but that is not an executable file: it is just a service definition file, like your own `/etc/systemd/system/bt-restart.service`.

Although you can omit the `.service` suffix with the `systemctl` command, you cannot omit any suffixes in the `ExecStart=` definitions, so `ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth` makes no sense. Even if you specified `.../bluetooth.service`, you cannot start a `.service` file this way.

If you just want to have your `bt-restart.service` to have the `bluetooth.service` available as it runs, you should add two lines in the `[Unit]` section of your `bt-restart.service`:

```
Wants=bluetooth.service
After=bluetooth.service
```

i.e. "`bt-restart.service` needs to have `bluetooth.service` running (but the system should not crash into recovery mode if it fails at boot), and `bt-restart.service` should run **after** `bluetooth.service` is started."

Then you won't need the `ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth` line at all.

Depending on the exact behavior you're after, you might want to use `BindsTo=` or `PartOf=` in place of `Wants=`.

If you explicitly want to **always stop `bluetooth.service` if it's running and restart it** within your `bt-restart.service`, then you should replace your `ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth` with:

```
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

But if your goal is to just have your `enable-bt.sh` script run every time `bluetooth.service` is started or restarted, then the combination of

```
PartOf=bluetooth.service
After=bluetooth.service
```

should do the job.